# Crystal Report Error load report failed Asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have developed a Crystal Report portal which is working with other report but i am trying to host some reports it showing this error" Error load report failed". I am not sure why it is happening other reports is working same stuff.Any suggestion please

```
var p = Request.QueryString["P"].ToString();
var appId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["appId"].ToString());
var HE = new HIVAIDSEntities();
var app= HE.ApplicatioNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Hivrp_app_name_pk == appId);

//SQLReport report = new SQLReport();
var report = new ReportDocument();
//   Application.StartupPath 
report.Load(filename: Server.MapPath(p));
//Get SQL Server Details
string zServer = app.Hivrp_server_name;
string zDatabase = app.Hivrp_database_name;
string zUsername = app.Hivrp_user_id;
string zPassword = app.Hivrp_password;

var ciReportConnection = new ConnectionInfo
{
    ServerName = zServer,
    DatabaseName = zDatabase,
    UserID = zUsername,
    Password = zPassword
};

//Assign data source details to tables**

foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in report.Database.Tables)
{
   table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
   table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo);
}

//Assign data source details to the report viewer**
if (this.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo != null)
{
   TableLogOnInfos tlInfo = this.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
   foreach (TableLogOnInfo tbloginfo in tlInfo)
   {
       tbloginfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
   }
}
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayPage = true;
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: I would first ask if you have set breakpoints in the current code and stepped through the code evaluating all variables to make sure that they give you the expected results..

Comment: ye it is giving